# passing parameter from access into sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

**REPHRASING QUESTION:**

i apologize for being unclear. i have a textbox and a button a form. when the button is clicked it runs this saved access query:

```
select * from sqlservertable where field=form!textbox.value
```

i have an access front end and sql server back end.

this query is not working. it doesnt like me passing this parameter `form!textbox.text`. is there an alternate way to pass the value of the textbox?

Comment: You want to pass it as an access variable or as a SQL @variable?

Comment: @JNK, i just want to pass the text from the textbox into the sql statement

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? I don't understand your question.

Comment: @everyone: woudl this be the right solution? http://www.blueclaw-db.com/accessquerysql/parameter_query.htm

Comment: When you say "runs this saved query" what do you mean? Does the button call DoCmd.OpenQuery? If not, it's unclear what you mean, since SELECT queries don't do anything other than display data (i.e., they perform no actions).

Comment: @david yes it does OpenQuery. it works when the backend is access but when the backend is sql server it is not working because the form!text thing

Comment: `Form!textbox.Value` won't work in Access, either. What's your real parameter? It really has to be of the form `Forms!NameOfForm!NameOfControl` for it to work in Access. I also see no reason why it should fail to work with a SQL Server back end, assuming it's an MDB/ACCDB with ODBC linked tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .Text property of an Access control is available only what that control has the focus.

Secondly, in Access, you refer to forms as members of the Forms collection, i.e., the collection of open forms.

So, you use:

```
  Forms!FormName!ControlName
```

Without specifying the Forms collection as the container object for the form, the Access expression service won't know where to find the control.

And as .Value is the default property of controls, you don't need to specify it, though if you want to be really picky and explicit and type more characters for no actual benefit in this context, you could use:

```
  Forms!FormName!ControlName.Value
```

But that won't behave any differently at all in this context (the only situation where it will is if you're trying to force evaluation of the control before passing it as a parameter of a subrountine, in which case without .Value you may end up passing a control reference instead of the value, which could be bad or it could be fine).

Comment: thanks so much for your help. i worded my question incorrectly by saying that i was passing the TEXT property, i was actually indeed passing the VALUE property and it wasnt working

Comment: But you weren't using the Forms collection.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the RecordSource property on the form (from code) with:

```
Form.RecordSource = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE [Occurrence Date] BETWEEN " & Text1 & " AND " & Text2
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. ive rephrased my question. please let me know if i can clarify anythign else

Comment: Try Me!Textbox instead of form!textbox.text

Comment: Also, if you're doing this by code I think you need to do a Me.Requery

Comment: at which point woudl i do the requery? it is working perfectly fine when the data is in access, not sql-server